# Check if my user has Process privilege

Tags: mysql

I am connected to a mysql database and trying to find out what all threads are running on server.

I am using `show full processlist` command but it only shows that the threads which my user is running. It may be the case that no other user is running the thread at this moment but I want to be sure if this is the complete list for the server.

[This section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) tells that to view processes from all users we have to have PROCESS privilege. I want to know if my user has process privilege? how can I see that.

Comment: SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;

Comment: @Riz thanks. Please make it as a answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get list of privileges for the current user as

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

Or for a specific user

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```